# How to add a Service on moqui startup?

Tags: moqui

I want to add apache ignite into moqui framework when moqui framework startup.
I tried to start ignite instance in `postFacadeInit()` method,and it worked.
But, is there any less intrusive way to solve this? such as make a component,and when i need ,i can put the component into the component folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Moqui Conf XML file you can use the webapp.after-startup and webapp.before-shutdown elements to specify actions (in XML Actions elements) to run. The run after the class loader adds jars from component lib directories to the classpath, so you can instantiate objects or call init/destroy methods and such.

Just an FYI: the next version of Moqui includes Hazelcast to do things very similar to what Apache Ignite does. Some of the functionality is already in the moqui/moqui-framework repository, and more is implemented and will be merged soon.

Comment: Thanks,i think the way to solve this is not good(with Moqui Conf xml).
Because the after-startup is bind on webapp,this meaning my component should know the webapp info that i can override the conf for add after-startup.I am i understand right? 
if yes,i think,if moqui framework can provide some **lifecycle callback**,such as some interface:`AfterMoquiStartup`,`Before BeforeMoquiShutdown`,PreMoquiFacadeInit,PostMoquiFacadeInit... And in component.xml, i can register my lifecycle callbacks,when moqui load my component,it can do my lifecycle implements automatically,what do you think my idea?

Comment: Could you be more specific? How would that be different from what is currently supported?

Comment: Looking at this more I see one difference: if Moqui is not initialized in a servlet context (including for tests, etc) then these would not be run. I'll think on this, adding a more generic mechanism for components to init and destroy (maybe an interface to implement). Feel free to create an issue in moqui/moqui-framework if you'd like to track this potential feature.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to add this feature myself,and i think you may need more time to focus moqui main feature.BTW, i really like moqui,but my company use ofbiz,these days, i compared more between ofbiz and moqui, and i think wether in architecture or the convenience for develop,moqui is better than ofbiz.

Comment: Last week I started working on reducing dependencies on various tools used in the framework, especially where standard interfaces make it possible to plugin other tools. Part of this effort, the ToolFactory interface and the configuration and code that manage these, should meet your needs. The code is in the moqui/moqui-framework repository on github.